# Not updated data after post (mvc razor)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using "Composite C1" cms, mvc and razor view engine.
Some page should show list items and user could filter data by some criteria.
First part works fine (items are shown without problems), I have problem with second part - filtered data is not updated, page displays old data.

I have ItemsController:

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ZeroCacheProfile")]
    public ActionResult Filter()
    {
        // Initialize all filter comboboxes for Items page
        // ...
        return View(new MyModel());
    }

    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ZeroCacheProfile")]
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        // Set first default items
        ViewBag.Items = (IEnumerable)GetRandomItems(8);

        return View(new MyModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(true)]
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ZeroCacheProfile")]
    public ActionResult List(MyModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // Set filtered items
        // ...
        ViewBag.Items = (IEnumerable)itemList;

        return Json(new { Success = true, Filter = filter, ItemNumber = itemList.Count }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

And I have two views: "List.cshtml" - in order to display data and "Filter.cshtml" - in order to generate criteria to filter data.

"Filter" view has script that does query to /Items/List, - in  order to filter and update data.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search_button_filter").bind('click', function() {
            var $form = $("#filter_form");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Items/List/default.aspx',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Success) {
                        // Show report: amount of filtered items, etc.
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

I checked - "ActionResult List(MyModel model)" set correct filtered data in next code line

```
ViewBag.Items = (IEnumerable)itemList;
```

But "List" view continue to display previous data.

Probably, someone tell me way to solve my problem.

Thank you.

**New Update**

I remade my solution and it works now. The same two 'List' and 'Filter' views on my page, but without any Rest/Post, just Get and QueryString:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search_button_filter").bind("click", function() {
            var $filter1 = $("#filter1_search_filter").val();
            var $filter2 = $("#filter2_search_filter").val();
            var $filter3 = $("#filter3_search_filter").val();
            window.location.href = "@UrlUtil.ItemsPageUrl" + "?&filter1=" + $filter1 + "&filter2=" + $filter2 + "&filter3=" + $filter3;
        });
    });
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

But I have very small problem now. Amount of items is calculated in 'ActionResult List()' method (which initializes 'List' view), but I need display this value on 'Filter' view.
I tried to use TempData collection - set

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ZeroCacheProfile")]
public ActionResult List()
{
    TempData["AmountOfFilteredItems"] = null;

    Guid filter1;
    if (!Guid.TryParse(Request.QueryString["filter1"], out filter1))
    {
        filter1 = Guid.Empty;
    }

    Guid filter2;
    if (!Guid.TryParse(Request.QueryString["filter2"], out filter2))
    {
        filter2 = Guid.Empty;
    }

    Guid filter3;
    if (!Guid.TryParse(Request.QueryString["filter3"], out filter3))
    {
        filter3 = Guid.Empty;
    }

    List<MyModel> items;
    if ((filter1 == Guid.Empty) && (filter2 == Guid.Empty) && (filter3 == Guid.Empty))
    {
        items = GetRandomItems(8);
    }
    else
    {
        items = GetFilteredItems(filter1, filter2, filter3);
    }

    TempData["AmountOfFilteredItems"] = items.Count;

    return View(items);
}
```

value in 'ActionResult List()' method of 'Items' controller and return this value in 'Filter' view:

```
@model MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Items", "Filter", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "filter_form" }))
{
    <!-- Fill required data -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <font class="bold">@(TempData["AmountOfFilteredItems"].NotNull() ? TempData["AmountOfFilteredItems"] : 0)</font>
}
```

Just one problem this value is always delayed by one step/iteration - if real amount of items is '2' then view displays previous value '8'. And next time when real number is '0' then it displays previous real value '2'.

How I can solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "List" view continues to display previous data? Do you mean after the ajax request, or if you navigate back to /Items/List?

Comment: You didn't include the code inside "if (data.Success)" which looks like an important part, since that's where the data is being returned to?

Comment: Hi, I thought that when I was setting new (filtered) items into ViewBag.Items storage (in 'ActionResult List(MyModel model)' method during 'post'), then 'List' view (which uses this storage for initializing) would be updated automatically - 'List' view would bind new data and display it... I would not like to bind it inside 'if (data.Success)' client side manually, it would be better to find way to do it on server side.

Comment: I forgot to add that these two 'Filter' and 'List' views are on one the same page.

Comment: Can you post the full code of the action that includes getting the data and setting the TempData variable?

Comment: See my answer re: TempData vs ViewData, see if that solves the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML in the browser won't update unless you update it. The code in the browser is disconnected from what's happening on the server. If you use Ajax to send a request to the server, then you need to process the response and do something with it.

If you want to use Ajax, you need to make sure your List(MyModel) method returns a partial view, and then overwrite a section of your DOM with it.

However, the easiest thing might be to remove the Ajax and just handle it as a normal page postback - this will be much simpler. It's a little old, but there's some info on form posts in MVC here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx

Comment: thank you, I thought the same yesterday and remade a bit my solution - it works, but I have a very small problem. I don't know, it will ok to create new question if subjects/context are related, therefore I updated my current question.

Answer (score 0):

I just read that the purpose of TempData is to provide data for the "next" request, so I wonder if the "current" request only sees TempData from the "previous" request, hence it's out of step.

Try changing to ViewBag instead, and see if that fixes the problem.

Eg. in my Action I added:

```
ViewBag.ItemCount = 10;
```

(Note: it's a dynamic object, so you can make properties up as you go).

Then to display it, I added this to my view:

```
Count: @ViewBag.ItemCount
```

Seems to work as expected.

Comment: ViewData returns 'null' always. And I think that it's ok, because 'get' and 'set' of ViewData are different scope in this case - 'set' is in 'List' action, 'get' is in 'Filter' view.

Comment: Hmm, I think it should work, but I actually meant ViewBag. I've updated my answer - I've just tested this and it seemed to work fine :-)

Comment: Mate, ViewBug and ViewData are the same (much similar). But it doesn't matter. Did you try to use 2 different Views (with 2 different actions in controller) on one page or just 1 view on one page???

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you were using it twice. Can you not also set the value into the ViewBag in the Filter action, or also set it in TempData for use in Filter view?